# c# unity2D handling multiple backgrounds

Tags: c#, background, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a scene in `Unity2D` with 3 backgrounds named Stone, Scissors and Paper. These 3 are relatively small backgrounds. I also have a screen size background like wallpaper.

Now, I put a `Button` outside of these 3 backgrounds and I want to switch between them when I hit that button. I mean there is 1 button, and lets say now the stone background is visible and the other 2 are not, when I hit that button, the stone background should be vanish and the paper background should be visible. When I hit that same button again in this situation, the paper background should vanish and the scissors background should be visible. And after that, the cycle should return to the stone background again if I hit that button.

I hope I explained right. How can I do that? Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:** I wrote this code, and it gives `NullReferenceException` in line 29.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NextCountry : MonoBehaviour {

    MainGame game;
    public GameObject stone;
    public GameObject paper;
    public GameObject scissors;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        game = MainGame.getInstance ();
        stone = GameObject.Find("StoneView");
        paper = GameObject.Find ("PaperView");
        scissors = GameObject.Find ("ScissorsView");
    }
    public void OnBackgroundChange(string next)
    {
        if (next == "paper")
        {
            stone.SetActive(false);
            paper.SetActive(true);
            scissors.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can do it like this 
place all three into the scene and when you hit the button make the transform.position.z of the one you want to be shown equals to 0 and other 2 make it like 100 or something .. in that way there is no way he can see them :P since you have 3 backgrounds this should work fine 
there is another way it's a little more complicated so if that doesn't work out I'll give you the other one in comment or something

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is, how can I reach these 3 backgrounds from the same script? If I can reach them, I can use "isHidden" too.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right you can use isHidden you cant reach them with GameObject.find("name in the scene"); 

Comment: I figure it out. At the beginning, they all have to be active.